# Selecting driver definition when adding a Hibernate configuration in Eclipse (SQL Server)

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jdbc

I try to add a new hibernate configuration in Eclipse Neon. Therefore I've installed the JBoss Tools and opened the Hibernate perspective to add a configuration.

Next steps I've done:

- click on 'new database connection'
- select 'SQL Server'
- create new driver configuration
- selected 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012 JDBC driver" from the list of avaibale driver templates
- added the sqljdbc.jar to the JAR List
- added some (at first) dummy properties

--> now I could click ok and save my driver definition

The problem:
As seen in the image below, I can now choose the driver defintion, but I still get the message that I need to select a driver from the list. I can't test the connection or choose any aditional properties.

[image]

Where do I have to search for the error?

Thank you!